# Wrap <li> tags with <ul> tag in RTE text

Tags: java, css, html, tags, jsoup

I have an RTE text which is formatted as below:

```
<li> text </li> 
<li> text </li> 
<p>  text </p> 
<p>  text </p>
<li> text </li>
<li> text </li>
```

The problem here is, The "li" tags are not wraped within "ul" tag. I want to achieve this using Java since I am writing a migration script. I found answers in Jquery but it is hard to find in solution like this in Java.

Note: not sure if it's important or not but this is an RTE text given by the client in Excel sheet for migration.

The desired result from above text is below:

```
<ul>
   <li> text </li> 
   <li> text </li> 
</ul>
   <p>  text </p> 
   <p>  text </p>
<ul>
   <li> text </li>
   <li> text </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There's not enough context here for us to answer. Are you processing this in a DOM or in a plain text stream?  Please explain the input and output mechanisms.

Comment: It is plain text stream. I am assigning jcr property to the RTE component so the component will render and convert this plaintext. but Need a way in java to parse this plain text to add <ul> tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just getting it back as a string, here is a regex solution that should work or at least serve as a good starting point.

```
String pattern1 = "(?<!</li>\\s{0,100})(<li>)";
String replace1 = "<ul><li>";

String pattern2 = "</li>(?!\\s{0,100}<li>)";
String replace2 = "</li></ul>";
```

The pattern looks for `<li>` tags that aren't preceded by an `</li>` tag (ignoring any white space in between them) then replaces them with an opening `<ul><li>` tag.

Then it looks for any `</li>` tags that aren't followed by a `<li>` tag and replaces with a `</li></ul>` tag

Full code below, or [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tpcg.php?p=IlZ1Kr) is a live example

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches {

   public static void main( String args[] ) {
      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String input = "<li> text </li> <li> text </li> <p>  text </p> <p>  text </p><li> text<span>more test</span> </li><li> text </li>";
      String pattern1 = "(?<!</li>\\s{0,100})(<li>)";
      String replace1 = "<ul><li>";

      String pattern2 = "</li>(?!\\s{0,100}<li>)";
      String replace2 = "</li></ul>";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r1 = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
      Pattern r2 = Pattern.compile(pattern2);
      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m1 = r1.matcher(input);

      input = m1.replaceAll(replace1);

      Matcher m2 = r2.matcher(input);
      input = m2.replaceAll(replace2);
      System.out.println(input);

   }
}
```